# Can you have Javascript running on the browser at full performance even when I'm on a different tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, async-await

There are many instances where I leave a looped async function running on a chrome tab (for testing) but whenever I leave the lab, Chrome seems to significantly lessen the speed at which js runs on that tab. Is there any way to have full cpu power for running javascript on a different tab than that I am currently on?

For example, when I'm running a js test file on tab 1 with localhost:3000 but I go off another tab to do something else for a while. When I come back to tab 1, I see minimal progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

> Background tabs can have a dramatic negative effect on browser performance, especially on battery life. To mitigate this, Chrome has been placing various restrictions on background tabs for the last several years.

> ...

> Chrome provides the --disable-background-timer-throttling flag for use cases like running test suites and other user-sanctioned heavy computations.

So basically just launch chrome with the `--disable-background-timer-throttling` and you should be good to go

Comment: So there's no way of just setting 1 tab to be like this. Correct?